# How to make a connection string and sql helper command in class on c# windows forms

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Is it anyone out there that can help me make a SqlHelper script in class code in a c# windows form. I want Sqlscalar and sqlNonquery and sqlexecute in the same script and after that I want the command to do the requested things in c# windows form.

With Best Regard
Jensen from Norway

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, first of all read read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask before you ask a question! Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: maybe this link will be helpfull for you http://dotnet-assembly.blogspot.co.at/2012/12/c-sql-helper-class.html

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started, here is some code I wrote, here here an Insert

```
    public static void DbInsert(string table, string[] columnNames, string[] datatoadd)
{
    //string table name, column names to be updated, data as string in array
    //string[] strColumnNames = { "test1", "test2", "test3", "test4" };
    //string[] strValues = { "value1", "value2", "value3", "value4" };
    //Database.DbInsert("tblName", valscn, vals);


    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString("LiveConnection");
    string tblValues = "";
    string tblValuesCN = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < datatoadd.Length; i++)
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + i.ToString(), datatoadd[i].ToString()));
        tblValues = tblValues + "@" + i.ToString();
        if (i != datatoadd.Length-1)
        {
            tblValues = tblValues + ",";
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.Length; i++)
    {
        tblValuesCN = tblValuesCN + columnNames[i].ToString();
        if (i != columnNames.Length - 1)
        {
            tblValuesCN = tblValuesCN + ",";
        }
    }

    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    sqlCmd.CommandText = "Insert Into " + table + "(" + tblValuesCN + ") Values (" + tblValues + ")";

    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    sqlConn.Close();
    sqlCmd.Dispose();

}
```

Here is an update:

```
    public static void DbEdit(string table, string[] columnNames, string[] datatoadd, string whereclause)
{
    //string[] strColumnNames = { "Activate" };
    //string[] strData = { "Activated" };
    //Database.DbEdit("tblName", strColumnNames, strData, "id='" + activationresponse + "'");

    SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection();
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    sqlConn.ConnectionString = ConnectionString("test");
    string tblValues = "";
    string tblValuesCN = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < datatoadd.Length; i++)
    {
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@" + i.ToString(), datatoadd[i].ToString()));
        tblValues = "@" + i.ToString();
        if (i != datatoadd.Length - 1)
        {

        }


        if (columnNames[i].ToString() != "")
        {
            tblValuesCN = tblValuesCN + columnNames[i].ToString() + "=" + tblValues + ",";
        }



    }
    tblValuesCN = tblValuesCN.Remove(tblValuesCN.Length - 1, 1);
    sqlCmd.CommandTimeout = 0;
    if (whereclause != "")
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Update " + table + " Set " + tblValuesCN + " where " + whereclause;
    }
    else
    {
        sqlCmd.CommandText = "Update " + table + " Set " + tblValuesCN;
    }
    sqlConn.Open();
    sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    sqlConn.Close();
    sqlCmd.Dispose();

}
```

You can make a read method using nonquery or whatever you want, but these two will get you started with inserting and updating, especially with the link SINE just posted, you can take some from there.